# Append TD('s) after td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have the following html:

```
        <tr>
            <td class="success" rowspan="1">Viability</td>
            <td data-rowh="-Checksum">Viability-Checksum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-rowh="-Request">Viability-Request</td>
        </tr>
```

What i want to do is to `add columns after each td` with the data-attribute `data-rowh`.
So It would look like this (testdata):

```
        <tr>
            <td class="success" rowspan="1">Viability</td>
            <td data-rowh="-Checksum">Viability-Checksum</td>
            <td data-check="P1-Checksum">Test P1</td>
            <td data-check="P2-Checksum">Test P2</td>
            <td data-check="P3-Checksum">Test P3</td>
            <td data-check="P4-Checksum">Test P4</td>
            <td data-check="P5-Checksum">Test P5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-rowh="-Request">Viability-Request</td>
            <td data-check="P1-Request">Test P1</td>
            <td data-check="P2-Request">Test P2</td>
            <td data-check="P3-Request">Test P3</td>
            <td data-check="P4-Request">Test P4</td>
            <td data-check="P5-Request">Test P5</td>
        </tr>
```

I presumed it would work using the following function (apperantly not)

```
        $('[data-rowh]').each(function (rIndex, rValue) {
            $.each(data.items, function (index, value) {
                rValue.after("<td data-check='" + value.name + "-" + rValue.data("rowh") + "'>test " + value.name + "</td>");
            })
        });
```

When I use the [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function for `rIndex` or `rValue`, i'm getting the error: `the property of the method after is not supported by this object`. Any idea on what i'm doing wrong?

**Note:** for those interested milestones looks like:

```
"items" : [  
{  "msId": "000104",  "name": "P1",  "msdescription": "Augustus" }
{  "msId": "000105",  "name": "P2",  "msdescription": "Descr" }
{  "msId": "000106",  "name": "P3",  "msdescription": "Test" }
{  "msId": "000107",  "name": "P4",  "msdescription": "456798" }
{  "msId": "000108",  "name": "P5",  "msdescription": "Autumn" }
]
```

Comment: How many tds you are trying to append?

Comment: @N55PEC can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Mr_Green: The amount is determined by the length of the items-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `.each()` loop over a jQuery object, you're working with the actual DOM node when you reference the value (or `this`), **not** a jQuery object. In order to use jQuery functions, such as `.after()`, you need to wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
$(rValue).after(...);
```

Comment: I didn't know that, thanx for that information. wrapping it inside a jquery-object did solve it for me.

Comment: @N55PEC Wrapping it in a jQuery object will resolve the error message you reported, so what's the new problem? Are there still errors in the console? What is/isn't happening that's not what you're expecting?

Comment: Now it appears to be working though. I just forgot the wrap the  `rValue.data("rowh")` in a jquery object aswell (how silly of me). When i changed it to `$(rValue).data("rowh")`it works smoothly